# Loading files without a pattern to database

Tags: database-design, file-upload, batch-file

I'm redesigning a database and I'm really uncomfortable with one of the approaches being used today that I want to replace.

A very high volume of data is loaded from *.csv files which do not have a defined format at different times. The volume is related to different customers

So the approach is to create a table for each new customer and keep it being loaded constantly. Problem is that there are constantly new tables being created for each customer and they do not match and are difficult to manage and query.

I've already thought about creating a table which would contain all the data and some columns to control from which customer/table they were, but I'm still thinking that might create a too big table that's even harder to manage or slow because of size.

Are there any other approches that I might be missing regarding load of files with a non-regular format? By non-regular, I mean that each file can have different columns (quantity and format).

Comment: I'm not working on the project anymore, but today I realize how a schemaless db would solve the problem almost seamlessly.

Answer (score 2):

This is one application where I would use a database to manage the *.csv files, but I wouldn't put the *.csv files in the database.  I've done something similar with a photograph database.

Basically, I would have one table to manage the *.csv files.

```
CSV Files
---------
File ID
Customer ID
Template location on disk
CSV file location on disk
```

The File ID is an auto incrementing integer.  The Customer ID is an integer pointing back to the Customer table.

The template location on disk is a String that points to the template location on disk.  The template is a flat file that lists the columns in the corresponding CSV file, in column order.  The format of the template file is up to you, although your CSV engine will have to process it.  This template is created manually for CSV files without column headers, and could be created programatically for CSV files with column headers.

THe CSV file location on disk is a string that points to the CSV file location on disk.

You could have other important columns on this table, like the CSV file received timestamp.  I've left these fields off to keep the explanation simpler.

For each CSV file that you want to query, you would read the CSV Files row from the data base.  Then your CSV engine would:

- Read the template
- Process the CSV file
- Return the desired results, or null if this template doesn't contain the desired columns.

The database would maintain the index to the template and *.csv files on the disk.  The CSV engine would process the template and *.csv files, returning the desired information.

Comment: Got it, it's a really interesting approach to the issue, noted! Thanks